# Как и где редактировать что б при выводе CSS в Yii 2 в конце ссылки добавлялся слэш?

Tags: php, yii2

Как я понял вывод производит функция

```
<?php $this->head() ?>
```

Но никак не пойму где ее редактировать, уже много че облазил и гуглил но не нашел нужного решения.

Comment: Вариант 1 - `$this` это экземпляр класса либо приложения (смотря где вызывается). Поставьте нормальный IDE (например, PHPStorm), тогда при клике на `head` с зажатой клавишой `shift` Вы попадете в эту самую функцию. Если без IDE, то ищите в классе, в котором данная функция используется, либо во всем приложении. Вариант 2 - поиграйте с роутингом

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй в конфиге прописать правило

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            ...
            //'urlSuffix' => '.html',
            'urlSuffix' => '/',  // <--- вот оно
        ),
```

Comment: в конфиге? где этот файл?

Comment: нашел, не помогло